# Form elements are not being POSTed in Opencart module

Tags: php, jquery, post, opencart

I am writing my own module, using for base a dummy one. I've completed a big part of the task, however I need to pass some extra settings. For this reason I added 2 new 'input' elements as you can see:

```
<form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form">
    <div id="hidset" title="Configure module" style="display:none;">
        <table>
            <tr><td>Apikey:</td><td><input type="text" name="my_module_apikey" value="5"/></td><tr/>
            <tr><td>User ID:</td><td><input type="text" name="my_module_uid" value="6"/></td><tr/> 
        </table>
    </div>
```

Then I wanted this div to open in a dialog box. So I wrote this function to do it:

```
function dialogSettings() {

 $( "#hidset" ).dialog({
    height: 250,
    width: 250,
    modal: true,
    buttons: { 'OK': function() {
                      $(this).dialog('close');
                }
             }
    });  }
```

Till here everything works as expected.

Now, if I choose to open the dialog - no matter if I change the settings or simply do nothing - click on its button to close it and choose to save the module, these extra 2 settings are NOT being POSTed. If I choose to edit the module again and this time not open the dialog, voila! the settings are being POSTed just fine with the hardcoded values.

Any idea about what causing the issue? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems that the .dialog method messes up the DOM hierarchy, so in a "magical" way, these input fields are no more part of the form... I'll try to ensure this and find a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I figured out the problem. It's because .dialog rearranges the DOM tree in a way that these 2 elements are considered any more part of the form, so they are not being POSTed with it. A possible solution (maybe a hack?) is to pass the dialog field values in hidden inputs inside the form, so they will always being included in the POST data.

If you have a better solution than this, please contribute!